# How to use javascript function variable in another script tag?

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically generating table rows uing javascript for loop:

```
<script>

var data = planData();
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    document.write("<tr data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#mapModel\">");
    document.write("<td>"+data[i]['id']+"</td>");
    document.write("<td>"+data[i]['sender']+"</td>");
    document.write("<td>"+data[i]['receiver\r']+"</td>");
    document.write("<td>"+data[i]['carrier']+"</td>");
    document.write("<td>"+data[i]['arrivalTimeEnd']+"</td>");
    document.write("<td> 10hrs </td>");
    document.write("<td> <i class=\"fa fa-circle-o text-success  mr-2\"></i> Delivered </td>");                                                       
}
</script>
```

After that I want to store the clicked row values in variable and I am able to do it by using below code in `msg` variable:

```
<script>
var msg;
//add event listener to table rows
let thetable = document.getElementById('mytable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]; 
for (let i = 0; i < thetable.rows.length; i++)
    {
        thetable.rows[i].onclick = function()
        {
            TableRowClick(this);
            var coords = document.getElementById('output').value;       
    
            
        }; 
    }                  

function TableRowClick(therow) {
    msg = therow.cells[0].innerHTML+'*'+therow.cells[1].innerHTML+'*'+therow.cells[2].innerHTML+'*'+therow.cells[3].innerHTML+'*'+therow.cells[4].innerHTML+'*'+therow.cells[5].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=msg;
  
    
};
</script>
```

Now the problem is, when I tried to use `msg` variable in which data is stored(in same html file but in another div tag), I am not able to use it.

```
<div>
    <script>
    
    document.write(msg)
    </script>
<div>
```

> Output: Undefined

Comment: i'd avoid using script tags as much as possible

Comment: Your `console.log()` is executed before you click on row, that why it's empty. Move it to `TableRowClick` function body

Comment: @DanielA.White  There is another div and I want to call on click of table row and after that the div will display the data according to rows data.

Answer (score 0):

You can only share the data between different script tag or files if we make the variables global or save them to browser storage.

You can save the message to window.

```
window.msg = 'your message';
```

You can access this variable in any file or script tag. but you have to make sure you are reading value after writing it.

Browser Storage, you can use any of localStorage, sessionStorage, cookieStorage.

but you have to make sure you are clearing these variables.

Comment: getting same warning `Undefuned`

Answer (score 0):

The msg access can be after it's definition, if you access before definition it will give you undefined. Below is the example.

```html
<head>
    <script>
        var msg = "hello"
    </script>
    <script>
        (function() {
            console.log(msg);
        })();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Test
</body>
```